# MS Word: Why isn't this wildcard find and replace working as expected? [screenshots inside]

Tags: microsoft-word, find

[Here I want to replace "80–90%" with "80%–90%".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq9V2.png)

But when I run replace, [this is what it puts out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfoW2.png)

Shouldn't it output "string 1 (the 0), a percentage sign, an en dash, and string 2 (the 90%)", in that order? To get the result that I am getting, you'd surely have to replace with "\1\2%–"?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the percent character (`%`) has a special meaning. Can you escape it somehow, for instance using a prepended caret character (`^`), such as in `^%`? Can you even better insert it using the _Special_ drop-down list?

Comment: Hm, I'm getting the same problem when trying to do a similar thing with a multiplication sign. Strangely it works fine if it's on text that I've written myself, but not if I'm editing someone elses text. 

After a bit more fiddling I think I've deduced it's because I have Track Changes on. If I turn that off it works as expected, which is a shame as tracking changes is a requirement of my job.

Comment: We do not know what to say, @tjay. You might have hit another kind of weird Software Fault. When the moonlight is blowing over us, our Regular Expressions are working. Can you please do the following favors for us, the others who do not have access to your setup: present your _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Operating System Version and your _Microsoft_ _Office_ _Word_ Word-Processor Version in your question body. Also, what does the _Special_ drop-down list produce for the Percentage Special Character (`%`) and for the Multiplication Sign Character (`*`)? Does it insert any kind of Escaping Character?

Comment: Sneaky workaround with track changes on - do 2 find and replaces instead.  Firstly search for your pattern but in the replace don't replace with anything except to add highlighting (assuming nothing else in your doc is highlighted).  Then do a second find for highlighted text with first part ie  ([0-9])[-–], and replace with \1%–.  That seems to avoid the issue with replacing parts.  Then remove all highlighting (select all and clear highlighting).

Comment: That would probably work, but the only problem is that I'm editing for clients, so I want to avoid the tracked changes getting particularly messy. My current workaround is to add functions to my macro to download two copies of the document, run through the wildcard edits without find and replace on, then use the compare feature to highlight any changes. Thanks for the help